# solution of a SDE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, probability-theory, proof-verification, stochastic-differential-equations

I am reading the book *Simulation and Inference for Stochastic Differential Equations with R Examples*. In the middle of page 44, there is a solution for $X_t e^{\theta_2t}$. I couldn't derive the same result.

According to the book, 
$$
dX_t = (\theta_1-\theta_2X_t)dt + \theta_3 dW_t,  ~~X_0=x_0
$$
with $\theta_3\in \mathbb{R}_+$ and $\theta_1$,$\theta_2 \in \mathbb{R}$.

We choose $f(t,x) = x~e^{\theta_2 t}$, and its first derivative with respect to $t$, its first derivative with respect to $x$, and its second derivative with respect to $x$ are
$$
f_t(t,x) = \theta_2~f(t,x)
$$

$$
f_x(t,x) = e^{\theta_2 t}
$$

$$
f_{xx} (t,x) = 0
$$

The solution from the book is 
$$
X_t e^{\theta_2 t} = f(t,X_t)=f(0,X_0)+\int_{0}^{t}\theta_2X_ue^{\theta_2u}du+\int_{0}^{t}e^{\theta_2u}dX_u
$$
$$
=x_0 + \int_{0}^{t}\theta_2 X_u e^{\theta_2u}du+\int_{0}^{t}e^{\theta_2u}\big\{(\theta_1 - \theta_2X_u)du + \theta_3 dW_u \big\}
$$
$$
=x_0+\frac{\theta_1}{\theta_2}\big(e^{\theta_2 t} -1\big) + \theta_3 \int_{0}^{t}e^{\theta_2 u} dW_u
$$

But my solution is

$$
X_t e^{\theta_2 t} = f(t,X_t)=f(0,X_0)+\int_{0}^{t}\theta_2X_ue^{\theta_2u}du+\int_{0}^{t}e^{\theta_2u}dX_u
$$
$$
=x_0 + \int_{0}^{t}\theta_2 X_u e^{\theta_2u}du+\int_{0}^{t}e^{\theta_2u}\big\{(\theta_1 - \theta_2X_u)du + \theta_3 dW_u \big\}
$$
$$
=x_0+ \int_{0}^{t}e^{\theta_2 u} \theta_1 du + \theta_3 \int_{0}^{t}e^{\theta_2 u} dW_u
$$
$$
= x_0+ e^{\theta_2 t} \theta_1 t + \theta_3 \int_{0}^{t}e^{\theta_2 u} dW_u
$$

What is my mistake?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the very last line you didn't calculate the integral

$$\int_0^t e^{\theta_2 u} \theta_1 \, du$$

correctly. Note that

$$\int_0^t e^{\theta_2 u} \theta_1 \, du= \frac{\theta_1}{\theta_2} (e^{\theta_2 t}-1).$$